# php yii form not clearing after submit

Tags: php, forms, yii

I use the following code in the UserController.php for registering new user

```
$model=new Users;

    if(isset($_POST['Users'])) {
        $model->attributes = $_POST['Users'];
        if ($model->register()) {               
            $model->setIsNewRecord(true);
            if ($model->save()) {
                Yii::app()->user->setFlash('info','User registered successfully!!! Please login to Continue.'); 
            } else {
                Yii::app()->user->setFlash('info','Sorry, an unexpected error has occurred!');
            }
        }   
    }
    $this->render('register',array('model'=>$model));
```

After successful registration, the register form retains the entered values. How can I clear this form?

The following is the form code in view file - Register.php

```
<div class="form">
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'register-form',
    'enableClientValidation'=>true,
    'clientOptions'=>array(
        'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
    ),
)); ?>    
    <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>           
    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'username'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'username'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'username'); ?>
    </div>

-----other textfields in div similar to the above one is present here - not show due to space limit-----

<div id="info"> <font color="red"> <?php foreach(Yii::app()->user->getFlashes() as $key => $message) {
    echo '<div class="flash-' . $key . '">' . $message . "</div>\n";
} ?></font></div>
<div class="row buttons">
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Register'); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: show register view file too

Comment: the view file is added

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can clear model attributes like below:

```
$model->unsetAttributes();
```

It is even better to redirect user to a page, even current page. Or simply unset `$_POST` values.

For example (if you don't want to redirect)

```
unset($_POST['Users']);
```

Or better:

```
$this->redirect('controller/action');
//or Yii::app()->request->redirect('controller/action');
Yii::app()->end();
```